# UI moving relatively to the camera when the camera moves

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I'm trying to make an inventory system in unity, and I'm experiencing a problem with the UI.I have attached the Main Camera to the player character, and I've set the render camera of the Canvas to that camera, howevever, when the character moves up or down, the UI also moves in the same direction (tough slower than if it wasn't following the camera at all). This doesn't happen when moving left or right. I have also tried to separate the camera from the PC, but the same problem presents itself.

This are my scripts:

```
public class inventoryUI : MonoBehaviour
{
  private Inventory inventory;

  private int EquippedItem;

  public bool showInventory;
  public float UItimer;
  public float UItime;

  private Transform InventorySlots;
  private Transform FirstSlotPos;
  [SerializeField] private Transform ItemSlot;
  [SerializeField] private Transform EquippedItemSlot;

  public void SetInventory(Inventory i, int EquippedItem)
  {
      inventory = i;
      this.EquippedItem = EquippedItem;
      RefreshInventory();
  }


  void Awake()
  {
      InventorySlots = transform.Find("InventorySlots");
      FirstSlotPos = InventorySlots.transform.Find("FirstSlotPosition");
  }

  [SerializeField]private float SlotSize;

  public void RefreshInventory()
  {
      if (!showInventory)
          return;

      foreach (Transform child in FirstSlotPos.transform)
      {
          if ((child != FirstSlotPos))
              Destroy(child.gameObject);
      }

      int x = 0;

      foreach (ItemData i in inventory.GetInventory())
      {
          RectTransform Slot;

          if (x == EquippedItem)
              Slot = Instantiate(EquippedItemSlot, FirstSlotPos).GetComponent<RectTransform>();
          else  Slot = Instantiate(ItemSlot, FirstSlotPos).GetComponent<RectTransform>();


          Slot.gameObject.SetActive(true);
          Slot.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(x * SlotSize, FirstSlotPos.position.y);

          Image icon = Slot.transform.Find("ItemIcon").GetComponent<Image>();
          icon.sprite = i.itemIcon;

          TextMeshProUGUI item = Slot.transform.Find("ItemNameDisplay").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
          item.SetText(i.itemName);
          item = Slot.transform.Find("ItemAmountDisplay").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
          item.SetText(i.amount.ToString());

          x++;
      }
  }



  void Update()
  {
      if (showInventory)
      {
          InventorySlots.gameObject.SetActive(true);
          UItimer -= Time.deltaTime;
          if (UItimer <= 0)
            showInventory = false;
      }
      else InventorySlots.gameObject.SetActive(false);
  }
```

---

```
public class PlayerInventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private inventoryUI invUI;
    public Inventory inv;

    private int EquippedItem;

    void Start()
    {
        EquippedItem = 0;

        inv = new Inventory();
        invUI.SetInventory(inv, EquippedItem);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        ItemObject i = col.GetComponent<ItemObject>();

        if (i != null)
        {
            inv.AddItem(i.GetItem());
            i.DestroyItem();
        }

        invUI.SetInventory(inv, EquippedItem);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            EquippedItem -= 1;
            invUI.showInventory = true;
            invUI.UItimer = invUI.UItime;
        }
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            EquippedItem += 1;
            invUI.showInventory = true;
            invUI.UItimer = invUI.UItime;
        }
       

        if (EquippedItem < 0)
            EquippedItem = inv.GetInventory().Count -1;
        else if (EquippedItem >= inv.GetInventory().Count)
            EquippedItem = 0;


        invUI.SetInventory(inv, EquippedItem);

    }
}
```

And this are my [camera settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvQoa.png) and my [canvas settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNfed.png)

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HgIe.png) is how the scene is set up.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use 2 cameras, UI camera and main camera. Set UI camera `Culling Mask` to UI layer (or whatever layer you set), `Clear Flags` to depth only then make sure UI Camera have higher depth than your main camera